# Rails 4 : Brakeman is giving xss issue for js.erb files and not to .html.erb files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, xss

I am using brakeman security tool to find the security issues in my web application. Brakeman is showing me two xss attacks in the `js.erb` extension file.

below is my js.erb file

```
<head>


<script>

$(function () {

    Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function (color) {
        return {
            radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
            stops: [
                [0, color],
                [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
            ]
        };
    });

    // Build the chart
    $('#highpie1').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                   point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            var scan_result = this.name
                            value = this.y;
                             //alert(" 1. click on ok Button to see Data")
                             location.href ="/batches/drilldown_result?scan_result="+scan_result; //Will take you to Google.

                           }
                        }
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'calculated',
            size:'40%',
            data: <%=  @result1 %> ***************** I am getting xss attack here
        }]
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="highpie1"></div>
<p id ="tsv">
</body>
```

I solved these xss issues by using sanitize method that rails provides to escape string.

But my question is in my other `html.erb` view files i am showing model attributes without sanitizing them. why brakeman is not giving xss attack issue for these files `html.erb` file and giving only to `js.erb` file. Does rails 4 automatically escape model attributes for `html.erb` file??

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing the code. Please show the relevant parts of the templates where you are seeing warnings and where you expect to but are not.

Comment: i have added my js.erb file where i am getting xss attach issue .. see line at the end of the code for error... here i am simply putting rails variable value into javascript.. if i am getting xss attack here js.erb files then i should get error in .html.erb file because there also i am printing value of rails variable and showing the output to user in the form of view.

Comment: Thank you for updating the question. However, it would be most helpful to see the warning (which would include the actual output and the value that's causing the warning). The code above would not normally produce a warning.